# How to print a occuring unique name in a group in CSV file in Python

Tags: python

I want to print a particular name from the column and its data in csv.

For example:

```
[**Joseph**, 1923, **503**]

[Josephine, 1945, 1301]

[Josephina, 1952, 66]

[**Joseph**, 1999, **3498**]
```

I want to get Joseph only and the total for line 2, and I can't use Panda yet.

That output should look like this:

**Joseph: 4001**

but instead its shows all the names with Joseph like joseph**ine**

This is my code:

```
import csv,
import itertools, 
import operator

levelgetter = operator.itemgetter(0)

col2sumgetter =operator.itemgetter(2)

baby_name = input("Enter the first name to analyze: ")

 with open("baby_names.csv", "r") as file:

    reader = csv.reader(file)
    name = lambda row: levelgetter(row)
    sorted_rows = sorted(reader, key=name)   
    for level, group in itertools.groupby(sorted_rows, key=name):
        if baby_name in level:
            total = sum(int(col2sumgetter(row)) for row in group)
            print(level, total)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a csv file `file.csv` like so

```
Joseph, 1923, 503
Josephine, 1945, 1301
Josephina, 1952, 66
Joseph, 1999, 3498
```

You can use the following code to get what you want using `csv.DictReader`.

```
import csv

baby_name = input('Enter the first name')

with open('file.csv') as file:
    rows = list(csv.DictReader(file, fieldnames = ['c1', 'c2', 'c3']))

res = {}

for row in rows:
    if row['c1'] == baby_name:
        res[baby_name] = res.get(baby_name, 0) + int(row['c3'])

print(res) # {'Joseph': 4001}
```

To get total just do `res.values()`, that will print total without name.

Comment: I am very new here, how do I accept it as solved? Also, can you do another option for just the total number for c3? --> Total is 4001 without the name?

Comment: Thank you so much @python_user. That worked for just showing the total. Found it and  accepted the answer.